# How do I get rid of SNI.dll when publishing as a "single file" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net, winforms, publish

I'm trying to publish a very simple C# .Net 5.0 WinForms application (single file output) as a test case for porting from the .Net Framework v4.6.1 (what it was previously) while using Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.2. The Publish options are as follows:

- Configuration: Release | Any CPU
- Target Framework: net5.0-windows
- Deployment Mode: Framework-dependent
- Target-Runtime: win-x64
- Produce Single File: **Enabled**
- Enable ReadyToRun Compilation: Disabled

Although the build works fine and merges the two source assemblies into a single output executable, it also includes SNI.dll in the output directory. The application will not start without this DLL in the same folder as the executable so my question is: **How do I remove the dependency on SNI.dll so it does not get included with the published executable and is not required to run?**

The application is a simple front-end to generate random data using the Crypto-API. It does not include any database functionality whatsoever, which is why it's so confusing to me that SNI.dll is included in the output. As far as I can tell, SNI.dll is related to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, which I don't use

Any help with this would be most appreciated. Cheers

PS. I should mention, all my attempts to Google this fault have turned up articles about "SNI.dll Missing", "SNI.dll failed to load" or some other variant of that

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I faced the same problem as yours and found the solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#other-considerations). It turns out that native libraries are not bundled in the single file executable by default. You must set the flag `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` to `true` to get this behavior.

You might also want to check your .deps.json file (from your build folder) to see how you got this dependency in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Simon. The link you provided helped to answer half of my question (the most important half). By adding <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract> to my publish XML file, SNI.dll is now at least embedded in the .exe so it's not visible. One day I hope to find out why it's there at all since I can't even find a reference to System.Data anywhere in my entire solution, but you've been a big help. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Simon. If you want the final solution in brief Solution: adding <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract> to my publish XML file. like this: <Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Answer (score 8):

As Simon V. stated, you can work around this issue by adding `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` to your project file and setting it to `true`.

tl;dr
Dotnet's Windows runtime depends on sni.dll.

> One day I hope to find out why it's there at all since I can't even find a reference to System.Data anywhere in my entire solution, but you've been a big help. Cheers

-- [HumanBean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9393918/humanbean)

> You might also want to check your .deps.json file (from your build folder) to see how you got this dependency in the first place.

-- [Simon V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1642427/simon-v)

Given a publish directory path of "bin\Release\net6.0-windows\win-x86\publish", check in the parent directory (win-x86, the RID) for a file named "$(AssemblyName).deps.json".

Search that folder for a dependency's assembly name or file name.

In my project's dependencies file, "sni.dll" is referenced by the following snippet:

```json
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0/win-x86",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0": {},
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0/win-x86": {
      ...
      "runtime.win-x86.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni/4.4.0": {
        "native": {
          "runtimes/win-x86/native/sni.dll": {
            "fileVersion": "4.6.25512.1"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

---

For the sake of further investigation, I'll include additional information.

All instances of sni.dll on my computers share the following attributes...

- ProductVersion: 4.6.25512.01 built by: dlab-DDVSOWINAGE016. Commit Hash: d0d5c7b49271cadb6d97de26d8e623e98abdc8db
- ProductName: Microsoft® .NET Framework
- Modified Date: 7/12/2017.

I wonder why the .NET 5+ runtimes depend on what appears to be a component of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation - I was porting a WinForm .net 4.7.2 app to .Net Core 6.0, and I saw a slew of warnings about `sni.dll` that looked like the following:

> WARNING: File 'sni.dll' of project output 'Publish Items from Unit Test (Active)' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

It turns out that this warning appeared when

- I used Configuration Manager to say the Setup project would *Not build with a Debug target*
- I specified the Debug target, did `Build > Clean` and `Build > Build`

When I switched to the Release target and did a `Clean` and `Build` and the warning went away.